# picture won't show after segue passing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

As the title says i am trying to show an UIImage in a UIImageview the problem is that it won't show. right before im showing it i passed it through a segue from another view. when i breakpoint i see that that UIImage is allocated but no picture will show, i have tried setting it to a static picture and that works fine.

The relevant code should be...

in FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    UIImage* img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
        NSLog(@"Bild hämtad!");
        [self moveImage];
    }
    else
    {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), Nil);
    }

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)image: (UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo{

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Bild sparad!");
        [self moveImage];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }
}
-(void)moveImage
{   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ImageEdit" sender:self];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Bild Flyttad!");

}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:self
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ImageEdit"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setMImage:image];
    }

}
```

In ImageEditController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [imageView setImage:_mImage];
    NSLog(@"Bild Visas!");
}
```

I know there is alot of code but i figured post to much than to little is better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever initialize the imageView?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imageView setImage:_mImage];
    NSLog(@"Bild Visas!");
}
```

If it has never been initialized, any function calls on it will just fail silently (calling a function on a nil pointer just doesn't do anything).

Comment: did i do it right?

"@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;"

and

"@synthesize imageView;"

Comment: Is the IBOutlet actually connected to an image view in interface builder? If isn't, then it is never initialized like I said. If it is a hooked up IB object it should be working.

Comment: have you tried debugging/stepping through your code to see if it is actually a valid image at runtime?

Comment: i see that mImage conatins 0x001f5aa0 is that enough to know its acctualy a picture there or could it be that way even if its empty?

Comment: That is the address of the object the pointer is referencing. The fact that it isn't 0x0 just means it is at least pointing to something (which is good). Does `imageView` point to something at the point where its image is set in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: no imageView does not point to anything at viewDidLoad. and that is a problem i pressume. i'm thinking that maybe i'm doing something wrong when saving the picture in the FirstViewController

Comment: That means that the imageView has not been initialized at that point. This is your problem. Setting an image will not have any effect because there is tehnically no UIImageView to set it in. Normally, by this point you would have either alloc,init'd it as in my example, or it would have loaded from a XIB file(if an element in the XIB is hooked up to the IBOutlet). The picture saving part has nothing to do with it.

Comment: iv'e also tried alloc init it and alloc initwithimage and none of the ways work. though it gets a pointer now.